# CPython: Dynamic module does not define module export function error

Tags: python, cython, cpython

I just compiled my Python wrapper for C++ classes successfully. However, I am getting following messages when I am trying to load my module to the Python (through `import cell`):

```
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_cell)
```

I checked that the system is using the Python3 on all cases so this is not a Python version problem.
Below is my **setup.py** file:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules = cythonize(Extension(
           "cell",                                
           sources=["cell.pyx", "cell.cc"],     
           language="c++",                       
           extra_compile_args=["-std=c++11"],
      )))
```

Below is the dump for the generated **.so** file:

```
0000000000201020 B __bss_start
0000000000201020 b completed.7594
                 w __cxa_finalize@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000000530 t deregister_tm_clones
00000000000005c0 t __do_global_dtors_aux
0000000000200de8 t __do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
0000000000201018 d __dso_handle
0000000000200df8 d _DYNAMIC
0000000000201020 D _edata
0000000000201028 B _end
0000000000000630 T _fini
0000000000000600 t frame_dummy
0000000000200de0 t __frame_dummy_init_array_entry
0000000000000640 r __FRAME_END__
0000000000201000 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 w __gmon_start__
00000000000004e8 T _init
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
0000000000200df0 d __JCR_END__
0000000000200df0 d __JCR_LIST__
                 w _Jv_RegisterClasses
0000000000000570 t register_tm_clones
0000000000201020 d __TMC_END__
```

I really don't understand why the module is not loaded to the python because there was no error during the building process.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not call your extension/module `cell.pyx`, call it differently - for example `cycell.pyx`.

Why? The following steps are taken while extension is built

1. Cython generates file `cell.cpp` out of `cell.pyx`.
2. Compiler compiles `cell.cpp` to the object file `cell.o`.
3. Compiler compiles `cell.cc` to the object file `cell.o` and overwrites the object file created from `cell.pyx`.
4. Linker links both `cell.o` files (but it is in reality only one) - in the result there is nothing what was defined in `cell.pyx`/`cell.cpp` in particular `PyInit_cell`.

By renaming the Cython-file you avoid that the object-file is overwritten.

Clearly, another option would be to rename your c++-file.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess you are my savior today :)